# Arabic url is not working in WordPress on Windows IIS Server

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, server, wpml

Urls with Arabic slugs are going to 404 on IIS Windows Server and working fine on Apache server.

When I have Arabic in URL like `/ar/product-categories/الأرز/`

It is redirecting to 404 when I edit the slug into English it's working

I have installed **wpml** for multilingual

My WordPress version is **4.3.2**, PHP version is **5.4.24**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issues is caused due to IIS does not recognize the multi language urls, so

Try adding the following code at the end of the <kbd>**wp-config.php**</kbd> file:

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL']) ) {
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'];}
```